# ASP.NET Core Multi-Tenant Site - How do you retain tenant id after session expires?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC site with multiple tenants. The tenant id is passed in on the query string on the GET request for the login and kept in session. Tenant names on navigation and some other tenant-specific customization are displayed.

If the user logs off I can grab the tenant id from session, put it back on the query string, and redirect to the login page so the user is able to re-log in just fine.

My problem is that when a session times out, MVC will redirect to my login page to begin a new session but I have no way to tack on the tenant id to the query string that I need in order to display the correct tenant info.

How can I retain a tenant id in a multi tenant environment without using session?

Comment: local storage, or a cookie maybe?

Comment: as @jpgrassi suggests: local storage, cookies, or even change the session time out

Comment: Nice post about it I have read recently https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2018/01/22/multi-tenant-web-apps-with-dot-net-core-and-postgres/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to pass tenant with each client query.

As an option, you may save selected tenant on login in a separate cookie and so you will know tenant while this cookie exists.

Also, keep in mind that a lot of site/apps allow users to change language/tenant at any time, not only on login.

Comment: I like the idea of keeping it in a cookie. 

Maybe I'm using the term "tenant" incorrectly but in this system, there's no reason for a user to ever switch from one tenant to another.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the session. Add the tenant id as a claim to the authenticated user. Instead of attaching the tenant id to the URL to set it initially, add it as a field in your login form. Presumably, authentication should be tied to tenancy anyways, so this should actually be more ideal, anyways. In other words, the user selects their tenant, and then enters their username/password to login. Then, you can also do checks such as whether the user is actually allowed to access that tenant, during sign-in, as well as set the tenant id claim.

Comment: My issue here is that I need to know the tenant _before_ my user logs in so the login page shows their tenant name/branding/etc. I don't want the user to know there are other tenants. I may be using the term "tenant" incorrectly here.

My site has multiple customers. Every nav bar on my site has the customer name and logo. I always want to display the correct name and logo on the nav and not even allow a user to log in if they have the wrong customer id passed in the query string on the login form.

Comment: Well, you can still do that *too*. However, there's no permanent way to persist that tenant id. No matter what you do, there is potential for it to go away, so you need some sort of game plan for how you will manage a user coming with no tenant id.